# Is there a Netbeans "tag" for line number

Tags: java, annotations, netbeans-8

Are there any Netbeans "tags" (ala @...) that will (upon compiling) insert the line number that the tag is on?  So, if the tag is on line 50, Netbeans will replace the tag with "50"?

I thought when throwing an exception, it might be a good idea to reference the line number in the .java file?

Comment: The stacktrace will automatically include the line number. You don't need to do that yourself.

Comment: If you "really" wanted to, you could use [`Throwable#getStackTrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()) which will return an array of [`StackTraceElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) which includes information like the line number.  Having said that, any `Exception` your throw, will already included this information any way, and most logger APIs provide this kind of functionality (logging the line number). Also, it's very slow

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you catch the exception, there won't be a stacktrace.  So, that's not what's wrong with the question.  Putting more thought into it, I should probably just customize the exception msg with something other than a line number so the source is more easily identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this as you are describing.

If you have an exception you can generally get the line number it was constructed on programmatically:

```
e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()
```

If you really want to get the line number of the current source line (and it doesn't sound like you do), I suppose you could do it like this:

```
new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber()
```

If you just want to print the stack trace, there's a method for that:

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

By default it will print the stack trace to System.err.  There are overrides to print to other places.  If you want to customize the output format you will have to call `getStackTrace()` and print it yourself.

Comment: I really did not want to get it programmatically, but rather simply be able to print it to the console during initial phases of development.  Anyways, needing that sounds like poor design, so i'll just customize the exception msg or handle it differently, though I hardly think it warranted a downvote.

Comment: @Brooks I added information on how to print the stack trace.  You probably want to look into using a logging framework like log4j that can help with these sorts of things.  For what it's worth, I don't think the question deserved a downvote either.

Comment: Thanks!  I think log4j is on the list to implement/add, just hasn't been done yet.  I hadn't considered simply printing the stacktrace, that should work fine for the point i'm at right now.